# luabind compiling error occurs

Tags: gcc, cmake, luabind

I am trying to compile luabind which I got from this [link](https://github.com/Oberon00/luabind). After I do

```
mkdir build
cmake ..
make VERBOSE=1
```

"cmake .." produces these lines,

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++-4.7
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++-4.7 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Boost version: 1.53.0
-- Found Lua52: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblua5.2.so;/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/build
```

"make VERBOSE=1" produces following errors.

```
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master -B/home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/build/CMakeFiles /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/build'
make -f src/CMakeFiles/luabind.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/luabind.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/build'
cd /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/src /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/build /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/build/src /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/build/src/CMakeFiles/luabind.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/build'
make -f src/CMakeFiles/luabind.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/luabind.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/build/CMakeFiles 2
[  1%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/luabind.dir/class.cpp.o
cd /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/build/src && /usr/bin/g++-4.7    -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/lua5.2 -I/home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master    -o CMakeFiles/luabind.dir/class.cpp.o -c /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/src/class.cpp
In file included from /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/luabind/object.hpp:38:0,
                 from /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/luabind/scope.hpp:28,
                 from /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/luabind/class.hpp:92,
                 from /home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/src/class.cpp:30:
/home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/luabind/detail/policy.hpp: In member function ‘T luabind::detail::enum_converter::apply(lua_State*, luabind::detail::by_value<T>, int)’:
/home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/luabind/detail/policy.hpp:498:21: error: ‘underlying_type’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
/home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/luabind/detail/policy.hpp:499:47: error: expected type-specifier before ‘integral_t’
/home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/luabind/detail/policy.hpp:499:47: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘integral_t’
/home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/luabind/detail/policy.hpp:499:47: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘integral_t’
/home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/luabind/detail/policy.hpp:499:47: error: ‘integral_t’ was not declared in this scope
/home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/luabind/detail/policy.hpp:499:83: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/luabind.dir/class.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/build'
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/luabind.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mwh/Desktop/Downloads/luabind-master/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What shall I do to correct this problem? I am using gcc 4.7.3, boost 1.53, Lua 5.2 in Ubuntu 12.04.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked out the project at revision 05c84a034e and built it on Mac OS X.  Here's what CMake told me at configure time:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.3
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/local/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Boost version: 1.53.0
-- Found Lua52: /opt/local/lib/liblua.dylib;
```

So I have GCC 4.7.3, Boost 1.53, and Lua 5.2.  I see you have GCC 4.7.3 also, but what about Boost and Lua?

Edit: Here's my compilation line from `make VERBOSE=1` for the first file:

> `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wdisabled-optimization -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wnoexcept -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-promo -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wno-deprecated-declarations -o CMakeFiles/luabind.dir/class.cpp.o -c class.cpp`

You on the other hand show this:

> `g++-4.7 -o CMakeFiles/luabind.dir/class.cpp.o -c class.cpp`

So the question is, where did all your compiler flags go?  The top-level CMakeLists.txt should contain this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++11")
```

And a bunch more.  Since you aren't getting those flags set, you need to figure out why.  You might try adding some `message("I am here")` debug statements in your CMakeLists.txt and running cmake again from scratch to see if the expected parts of the configuration are being executed at all.  The key thing here is that your compilation line lacks `-std=c++11`--that's why you get the error you have.

Comment: I have boost 1.53 and Lua5.2.

Comment: Try doing `make VERBOSE=1` and add the exact compilation line to your question.  Also, what OS?

Comment: I added the compilation lines to the question. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Show us what cmake tells you at configure time (the lines like what I put in my answer).

Comment: "cmake .." command doesn't produce much. However I included those lines as you wish.

Comment: You need to run it fresh.  Make an empty build directory and run cmake again.  You will see it output things like I posted.

Comment: Thanks John. I did not know that. Please see the updated question now.

Comment: Great.  I updated my answer--I see why it isn't working for you, but how you got it to be that way I can't say.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your valuable time @John Zwinck. I downloaded new source code. Now it's compiling. May be the developer corrected the bug. Thank you very much for your help.